# How to count the words in a figure or table?

Tags: academic-writing, graphics

In some journals, they ask that small figures should contain 300 words while large should have 600 words. So how we can count the words in a figure? secondly, If a figure contains 4 graphs like a,b,c,d, this will be a small or large figure?

Comment: Do you mean they "count" as 300/600 words, so if the article limit is 1200 words, if you have 1 small table, you have only 900 words?  Also, you *tagged* this as "creative-writing" which normally means novels, short stories, plays, but the questions seems to ask about journals -- are these academic journals?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Jawad.  I did a light edit on your post and also changed the tag from [tag:creative-writing] to [tag:academic-writing].  But perhaps [tag:technical-writing] or [tag:business-writing] is a better fit, please let us know.  Also, you're only supposed to have one question per post so you may wish to remove the one about small/large (it also isn't one we can answer because those terms are relative).

Comment: What do the people running the journal say? After all, if no one submitted articles there would be no journal, so they should be willing to explain the thinking.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the word count for figures and tables is based on the amount of space the figure or table takes up in the final print version of the article. Find an article in the journal you are submitting to and see how much space a figure of similar size might take up on the PDF or printed page.

Here is an example of sizing figures (artwork) from Elsevier: https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/artwork-and-media-instructions/artwork-sizing. Searching for author guidelines for your specific journal may give you more specific information.

Good luck on submission!